# Using html5 Canvas element in a Joomla Custom Html Module

Tags: html, canvas, joomla, joomla3.0

How can I use a html5 Canvas element in a Joomla Custom Html Module?

Is there an option I am missing? When ever I put the code in the module takes the canvas elements out.

Please Help If you need anymore information please ask.

Thanks!

Comment: Make sure you have filtering set to raw and that you are using a text editor not wysiwyg.

Comment: Yes I checked that. there was no filtering. I figured it out though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways that your HTML can have tags stripped out.

#### The Editor

The most common is actually the editor you have set up as default. e.g. if you using [JCE](http://www.joomlacontenteditor.net) this is famous for striping HTML because people haven't altered the **default** "Editor Profile".

In the JCE Control Panel, click on the Editor Profiles button.

Click on the Profile name that the user, usergroup or component is assigned to, eg: 'Default'

Click on the Editor Parameters tab, then on the Options tab and set it up to suite you.

#### Joomla Text Filters

Unless you're using a Super User account for everyday access (bad idea) you will need to set the user group of your account to have "No Filtering".

In the Joomla! 3.2 from the Global Configuration, click on the Text Filters tab (last one on the right). Check that your users group has "No Filtering" set, see the image below showing the standard test filter settings in 3.2:
[image: Joomla 3.2 Global - Text Filters]

#### When it still doesn't work

Turn off the editor while working on the module, i.e. go to your User profile and set the Editor to "None". Under "Basic Settings" in `User Manager:Edit Profile` change the `Editor` option to "None" as shown below:
[image: Joomla 3.2 Change Users Editor]

That way if you have "No Filtering" set, and no editor set you will be dealing with just the text being stored in the database and there will be nothing between you and the database to change it.

Comment: Yes this is what I had to do. Select no editor. I figured it out before I saw this post though haha

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to add some HTML or Script elements inside module or Article,

Joomla will automatically remove the scripts and tags is that your issue then take a look at below link it may help you.

[How to include html or PHP codes into Joomla article](http://www.walkswithme.net/how-to-include-html-or-php-codes-into-joomla-article)

Hope its helps.

Comment: that is great but it doesn't solve my problem. But I did solve my problem I will come back later and post the answer.